# Get a specific fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have an app which uses Tab navigation, a ViewPager, and ActionBarSherlock. In one of my fragments I get a photo using an intent but `onActivityResult` is called in the MainActivity and not the fragment. I want to get the fragment in MainActivity's `onActivityResult` and then call the fragments `onActivityResult`.

I've been trying all night but I cannot figure out how to get the fragment.

Basically I want to do something like this but I cannot get the fragment:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment");
  if(fragment != null){
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }

}
```

**Edit**:

TabsAdapter

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener , ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
private final Context mContext;
private final ActionBar mActionBar;
private final ViewPager mViewPager;
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
private final String TAG = "21st Polling:";

static final class TabInfo{
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
        clss = _class;
        args = _args;
    }
}

public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, ViewPager pager) {
    super(fa.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mContext = fa;
    mActionBar = fa.getSupportActionBar();
    mViewPager = pager;
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
    tab.setTag(info);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
    Object tag = tab.getTag();
    for (int i = 0; i<mTabs.size(); i++){
        if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }

}

public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
    return android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}


}
```

Comment: When did you add the fragment?

Comment: I have a class called TabsAdapted which takes care of that. Added it above.

Comment: And then I call mTabsAdapter.addTab() in my MainActivity onCreate()

Comment: I could be blind but it doesn't look like you've implemented the getItem() method in your adapter so you're never actually creating your fragments http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Comment: @CTulip it's the second last method in the sample above. Bolton's answer seems to have worked.

Comment: ok sorry I am blind. Glad you've worked it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `onActivityResult` will be called in both MainActivity and fragment, so you don't need to get the fragment. You must use different RequestCode for getting photo in the method `startActivityForResult()` and Make sure not to consume that RequestCode in MainActivity.